# E_INVALIDARG - Laravel Homestead VirtualBox error while executing VBoxManage

Tags: laravel, vagrant, virtualbox, homestead

System: Windows 10 Home 64bit, Vagrant 2.2.13, VirtualBox 6.1.16

Few seconds after running "**vagrant up**" command i'm getting this error:

> **There was an error while executing VBoxManage, a CLI used by Vagrant for controlling VirtualBox. The command and stderr is shown below.**

> **Progress state: E_INVALIDARG.**

> **VBoxManage.exe: error: Appliance import failed.**

> **VBoxManage.exe: error: Code E_INVALIDARG (0x80070057) - One or more arguments are invalid (extended info not available).**

> **VBoxManage.exe: error: Context: "enum RTEXITCODE __cdecl handleImportAppliance(struct HandlerArg )" at line 1118 of file VBoxManageAppliance.cpp**

I have already:

- Checked if there is no other virtual boxes running;
- Tried to run different commands: vagrant provision, vagrant reload --provision, vagrant up --provision, vagrant up, vagrant reload.
- Deleted ".vagrant" folder in the "Homestead" folder;

Still, not running.

My Homestead.yaml.
[image]

How to fix it and make Homestead run normally?

Thank you for your time and help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, in my case situation was solved by moving VirtualBox default machine folder to another drive, because there was not enough space on C drive, that was originally configured in VirtualBox.

In other words this error "Code E_INVALIDARG (0x80070057)" means you have not enough space for your virtual machine to start.

Change the drive and you should be good to go.

See attached image of the VirtualBox setting window:
[image]