# Problems with Vagrant installation

Tags: web, vagrant

Trying to execute `vagrant up` on the GIT bash, got this error:

```
$ vagrant up

Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
==> default: Importing base box 'laravel/homestead'...
There was an error while executing `VBoxManage`, a CLI used by Vagrant
for controlling VirtualBox. The command and stderr is shown below.

Command: ["import", "\\\\?\\C:\\Users\\simon\\.vagrant.d\\boxes\\laravel-VAGRANTSLASH- 
homestead\\11.5.0\\virtualbox\\box.ovf", "--vsys", "0", "--vmname", "ubuntu-20.04- 
amd64_1638302469897_32929", "--vsys", "0", "--unit", "11", "--disk", 
"C:/Users/simon/Desktop/VirtualBox VMs/ubuntu-20.04-amd64_1638302469897_32929/ubuntu-20.04- 
amd64-disk001.vmdk"]

Stderr: 0%...10%...20%...30%...40%...50%...60%...70%...80%...90%...100%
Interpreting \\?\C:\Users\simon\.vagrant.d\boxes\laravel-VAGRANTSLASH- 
homestead\11.5.0\virtualbox\box.ovf...
OK.
0%...
Progress state: E_INVALIDARG
VBoxManage.exe: error: Appliance import failed
VBoxManage.exe: error: Code E_INVALIDARG (0x80070057) - One or more arguments are invalid 
(extended info not available)
VBoxManage.exe: error: Context: "enum RTEXITCODE __cdecl handleImportAppliance(struct 
HandlerArg *)" at line 1119 of file VBoxManageAppliance.cpp
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Please give some more details. Which Virtual Machine did you try to install? Which operating system are you using? Try to first install VirtualBox for your OS, since vagrant depends on it.

Comment: @Tinxuanna I have VB already, I installed it for Kali Linux virtualization. I followed the instructions on a book, I did all the steps. I cloned Homestead Improved from GitHub, I don't even know the nature of this error.

Comment: Please try a complete reinstall of VirtualBox. Also, run Git Bash as administrator.

Comment: If I reinstall VB I'll lose Kali, I have things I can't delete. I tried to execute as admin, but with no results.

Comment: Please check this answer in stackoverflow. [E_INVALIDARG - Laravel Homestead VirtualBox error while executing VBoxManage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64729066/e-invalidarg-laravel-homestead-virtualbox-error-while-executing-vboxmanage). It seems like there is not enough space given for your VM. If you are stuck, feel free to ask again.

Answer (score 0):

#### Background

I had this problem. I was using a pseudo-user home directory, `demo`, for everything until a couple of days ago when I renamed it and created a real user "demo" there. I then divided its former contents to there and my real user's home directory. Finally, I updated `HOME` and `VAGRANT_HOME` environment variables.

#### New VMs won't come up

```
Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
==> default: Importing base box 'ubuntu/jammy64'...
There was an error while executing `VBoxManage`, a CLI used by Vagrant
for controlling VirtualBox. The command and stderr is shown below.

Command: ["import", "\\\\?\\C:\\Users\\john\\boxes\\ubuntu-VAGRANTSLASH-jammy64\\20221117.0.0\\virtualbox\\box.ovf", "--vsys", "0", "--vmname", "ubuntu-jammy-22.04-cloudimg-20221117_1668939345992_60394", "--vsys", "0", "--unit", "13", "--disk", "C:/Users/demo/VirtualBox VMs/ubuntu-jammy-22.04-cloudimg-20221117_1668939345992_60394/ubuntu-jammy-22.04-cloudimg.vmdk", "--vsys", "0", "--unit", "14", "--disk", "C:/Users/demo/VirtualBox VMs/ubuntu-jammy-22.04-cloudimg-20221117_1668939345992_60394/ubuntu-jammy-22.04-cloudimg-configdrive.vmdk"]

Stderr: 0%...10%...20%...30%...40%...50%...60%...70%...80%...90%...100%
Interpreting \\?\C:\Users\john\boxes\ubuntu-VAGRANTSLASH-jammy64\20221117.0.0\virtualbox\box.ovf...
OK.
0%...E_FAIL
VBoxManage.exe: error: Appliance import failed
VBoxManage.exe: error: Could not create a directory 'C:\Users\demo\VirtualBox VMs\ubuntu-jammy-22.04-cloudimg-20221117_1668939345992_60394' to save the settings file (VERR_ACCESS_DENIED)
VBoxManage.exe: error: Details: code E_FAIL (0x80004005), component MachineWrap, interface IMachine
VBoxManage.exe: error: Context: "enum RTEXITCODE __cdecl handleImportAppliance(struct HandlerArg *)" at line 1416 of file VBoxManageAppliance.cpp
```

I deleted the `.vagrant` directory and tried again to no effect.

#### Pre-existing VM now failing

This one was working shortly after creating the new user account, so I decided to check again.

```
john@dev ~/vms/vm_gp1 $ vagrant up
Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
Your VM has become "inaccessible." Unfortunately, this is a critical error
with VirtualBox that Vagrant can not cleanly recover from. Please open VirtualBox
and clear out your inaccessible virtual machines or find a way to fix
them.
```

#### VirtualBox

I looked in VirtualBox and saw this:

```
Runtime error opening 'C:\Users\demo\VirtualBox VMs\vm_gp1_default_1668795428444_91682\vm_gp1_default_1668795428444_91682.vbox' for reading VERR_ACCESS_DENIED (Access denied.).



F:\tinderbox\win-rel\src\VBox\Main\src-server\MachineImpl.cpp[1025] (long __cdecl Machine::i_registeredInit(void)).
Result Code:    E_FAIL (0X80004005)
Component:  MachineWrap
Interface:  IMachine {300763af-5d6b-46e6-aa96-273eac15538a}
```

My non-Vagrant VM could start, but Vagrant ones could not.

#### Drastic actions

I uninstalled Vagrant and installed the new version.

The problem did not go away.

I deleted the .vagrant.d directory.

Not a solution.

### Solution

I opened VirtualBox, File, Preferences, General. "Default Machine Folder" was still using the old demo directory. Changing that fixed it.

The actual "demo" account still refers to Users\demo, so this solution does scale to multi-user environments.